# How do i add custom fonts in the font awesome plugin??? Can it be done using EOT file?

Tags: custom-font, font-awesome, eot

I need to add some custom fonts to font-awesome and use it in my website. Will EOT be of any help in doing this? If so what is the procedure to add these custom fonts or is there any other way in which i can do this?